# Category Redirects to homepage

Tags: posts, htaccess

My `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm getting redirected to the HomePage but only on one WordPress category. The problematic category is `airlines`. eg. `url/airlines/test/`

Had this line previously in `.htaccess`, but deleted.

```
#RewriteRule ^airlines/(.*)/(.*).png$ ./upload-router.php?folder=$1&airline=$2 [L]
```

Also rebuilt permalinks.

I can fix this bug by changing `/%category%/%postname%/` to `/%category%xxx/%postname%/`, but of course I need how it was originally.

I can also FIX it by renaming category to `airlines2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed. There was conflict between slugs, which was hard to see at first, because project is large. :D Thanks.